# QR Code provisioning for fully managed device owned by company

Tags: android, qr-code, provisioning

I am trying to install custom DPC on my new factory reset tablet using QR code provisioning method. I have created the JSON and converted it to QR code for scanning.

I am able to scan the QR code and my custom dpc app is successfully installed. After which my device launcher screen is shown. I was expecting my deviceadmin receiver methods like `onEnable`, `onprofileprovisioningcompleted` to be invoked. I am trying to launch my activity from `onprofileprovisingcompleted` method.

I want to launch the activity automatically without user intervention. My home Activity and deviceadminreceiver is part of dpc app.I am unable to figure out why those methods are not invoked.

I have added toast statements and Notifications as well which never got executed. Please advice.

OS on the tablet is: Nougat.Please find the code below.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fateh.com.my.fatehdpc">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:label="DevicePolicyAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        android:exported="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_OWNER_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**MyDeviceAdminReceiver class file**

```
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver
{
    public static final String ACTION_PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS_CHANGED =
            "com.afwsamples.testdpc.policy.PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS_CHANGED";

    void showToast(Context context, String msg) {

       // Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        showNotification(context,msg);
    }

    public void showNotification(Context context, String message) {


        // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                // Set Icon

                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(message)
                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle("Testing")
                // Set Text
                .setContentText(message)
                // Add an Action Button below Notification

                // Set PendingIntent into Notification

                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(false);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Nadeem",
                "MyDevicePolicyReciever Received: " + intent.getAction());
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS_CHANGED:
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                Toast.makeText(context,"onReceive invoked ACTION_PASSWORD_REQUIREMENTS_CHANGED ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;
            case DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_PROFILE_OWNER_CHANGED:
                Toast.makeText(context,"onReceive invoked ACTION_PROFILE_OWNER_CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                break;
            case DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED:
                Toast.makeText(context,"onReceive invoked ACTION_DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(context,"onReceive invoked ACTION_DEVICE_OWNER_CHANGED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {

        UserManager userManager = (UserManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
        long serialNumber = userManager.getSerialNumberForUser(Binder.getCallingUserHandle());
        showToast(context,"Device admin enabled in user with serial number: " + serialNumber);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {

        showToast(context,"Device owner disabled");
    }



    @Override
    public void onProfileProvisioningComplete(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try
        {
            showToast(context,"onProfileProvisioningComplete");
            Intent launch = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(launch);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("nadeem", "onProfileProvisioningComplete Error " + e);
            showToast(context,"onProfileProvisioningComplete Error " + e);
        }

    }

    public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    }

}
```

MainActivity:  Its just blank activity with one button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I used NFC provisioning. The error was in the "receiver" declaration on AndroidManifest.xml (attribute exported="false").

On the "receiver" declaration, you set it "exported" as exported="true".
Too you add it the next actions: "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" and "android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"

Comment: I tried this just now did not help. I will be posting the code just in case someone can help after seeing the code. Thanks mate.

Comment: The "receiver" declaration seem correct and the implementation too. It's possible that exists a error in the execution of some method on the receiver (it's just assumption).

Comment: Your code is based on the Google project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc

Observation: you overridden the "onReceive" method (but do not use, I could try to comment) and you do not declare the action 
"android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" for "onDisabled" method.

Comment: Found something interesting. I was testing on Table (Asus) I have the above problem. I tried same thing on LG phone and works like charm. No changes nothing which mean nothing is wrong in the code. However this is what surprising and confusing me , as Pedro Luis mentioned the code that is posted above is copied from testDpc If i install test dpc it works as expected but and the above code does not though copied from testdpc.What else can be invoking these methods ?? suspected bootreceiver but i dont see any link in testdpc. Please please advice I want to crack this puzzle.

Comment: Found the problem but i haven't found the solution. Can any one help

Comment: Problem : If your package name is not "com.afwsamples.testdpc"  then methods from DeviceAdminReceiver are not getting invoked. I tried this on TestDPC application given by google itself. Any idea how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Is equals the "application Id" of the gradle file to the package name of the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes indeed . All occurrences are changed properly . Manifest , deviceadminreceiver, grade file etc

Comment: The TestDPC solves this problem by also declaring a `ProvisioningSuccessActivity` with a receiver action of `android.app.action.PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL`, which is what completes the provisioning (only on some devices?). I am also trying to figure out why I do not get a call to `onProfileProvisioningComplete`, but this workaround works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and found the solution. From the code snippet in the question, we can see that `onReceive` is overridden, but `super.onReceive()` is only called *sometimes* (when the switch statement reaches the default case).

A normal `BroadcastReceiver` only has [an abstract `onReceive`](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.java#327), which means there is no need to call `super`.

However, when implementing a DeviceAdmin, you extend `DeviceAdminReceiver`, which has [an important implementation for `onReceive`](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.java#1005).

```java
 999    /**
1000     * Intercept standard device administrator broadcasts.  Implementations
1001     * should not override this method; it is better to implement the
1002     * convenience callbacks for each action.
1003     */
1004    @Override
1005    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
1006        String action = intent.getAction();
1007
1008        if (ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
1009            onPasswordChanged(context, intent, intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER));
1010        } else if (ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED.equals(action)) {
1011            onPasswordFailed(context, intent, intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER));
1012        } else if (ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED.equals(action)) {
1013            onPasswordSucceeded(context, intent, intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER));
1014        } else if (ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED.equals(action)) {
1015            onEnabled(context, intent);
1016        } else if (ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
1017            CharSequence res = onDisableRequested(context, intent);
1018            if (res != null) {
1019                Bundle extras = getResultExtras(true);
1020                extras.putCharSequence(EXTRA_DISABLE_WARNING, res);
1021            }
1022        } else if (ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED.equals(action)) {
1023            onDisabled(context, intent);
1024        } else if (ACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRING.equals(action)) {
1025            onPasswordExpiring(context, intent, intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER));
1026        } else if (ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
1027            onProfileProvisioningComplete(context, intent);
1028        } else if (ACTION_CHOOSE_PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS.equals(action)) {
...
```

This default implementation of `onReceive` is what makes all the callbacks work. So, overriding it without calling `super` will prevent all the callbacks from working.

I made a similar mistake when implementing my receiver. Adding a call to `super.onReceive()` fixed it for me.

I know this answer is very late, but hopefully it helps someone.